# Rotate screen in mac os with terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I want to rotate screen in mac os with the help of commands in terminal.I was able to do so in linux with `xrandr` commands but not in mac os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no built-in way to do this, but [fb-rotate](https://github.com/CdLbB/fb-rotate) is a command line utility that should be able to do the job.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a terminal util for macOS that lets you rotate, change resolution, and position monitors on macOS. When I switched from Linux to macOS I really missed XRandR.

[displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) - also available via Homebrew `brew tap jakehilborn/jakehilborn && brew install displayplacer`

Comment: Have you tried it under macOS Catalina 10.15.7 yet? I have an iMac with two portrait mode screens attached, one each side of the main screen. It's probably an Apple bug, but since 10.15.7 has been released it seems that I can only have one portrait screen at a time actually in portrait mode. When I change one to portrait mode the other changes to landscape mode.

Comment: Never mind apparently I wasn't Thinking Different enough. The strange behaviour persisted through several reboots, but the screens showed correct orientations after I switched the whole machine off and swore at it a little. Love this tool, by the way! :)